# Use both internal and external activity LED?

Tags: config.txt, activity-led

With something like

```
dtoverlay=act-led,gpio=26
```

in `boot/config.txt` I can enable an external activity LED, which is useful if the Pi is in a case and the on-board LED cannot be seen. Unfortunatelly, this disables the internal LED, so when the external LED is disconnected (or broken), nothing can be seen at all, even if the case is open.

Is there a way to enable both, basically duplicating the LED status to the GPIO pin, instead of replacing it?

Comment: Use a different pin for the external?

Comment: @Steve Robillard, how would that improve the situation?

Comment: You could then have both working so if the external dies the onboard would still work.

Comment: @SteveRobillard I don't get it. The problem doesn't depend on which pin the LED is attached. Setting it to _any_ gpio pin seems to disable the internal one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative answer to duplicating a led is to create another in **/boot/config.txt** 
using `dtoverlay=gpio-led[,gpio|label|trigger|active_low]=<val>`

eg.
`dtoverlay=gpio-led,gpio=25,label=my_status_led,trigger=mmc0`
(this assumes that your existing *act_led* is using *mmc0* as the trigger.)
Once you reboot, it will magically appear in **/sys/class/leds/** as **my_status_led**

The trigger can be any value already used by *act_led*. 
See **/boot/overlays/README** for a list of settings for *dtoverlay=gpio-led* (scroll down to *Name: gpio-led* for a list of parameters.) 
Personally I would use *gpio26* since it is near *gpio21* which I use for my illuminated shutdown button.

Answer (score 0):

```
#act led now on gpio 25
dtparam=act_led_gpio=25
```

USE THIS FOR ALL RASPBERRY PI MODEL[PI1 to PI4]

or

```
#act led now on gpio 
dtparam=act_led_gpio=25
```

Comment: Did you read my question at all? I know how to set the LED to external. I want the internal _and_ the external LED to work simultaneously.

Comment: Welcome @XPXWORD! Your answer is a bit vague as it is; you've included the same code snippet twice. Could you add more details about your proposed solution? The [overlays README](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/blob/master/boot/overlays/README) doesn't seem to say anything about using two different pins for an activity LED but maybe you have some more info to share.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).